# Using OR statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue with the OR statement in my SQL SELECT in perl.

```
    ######################### Open File and Split The Data Into An Array ####################################
$input_data_file = '/var/www/html/JG/TG/tower_gather.txt';
open (DAT, $input_data_file)
          or die ("Could not open file!");

@raw_data = <DAT>;

close(DAT);
#########################################################################################################

$dbh_source2 = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=<ip-address>;port=<port-number>;sid=<sid>",'username','password');
$SEL = "SELECT DISTINCT SITE_NAME, SITEID, PE_DOWNLINK_PORT FROM CBHME.SERVICE_TOPOLOGY_VIEW WHERE LOWER(PE_FQDN) = ? OR PE_OSPF_LOOPBACK_IP = ?";


$fqdn = $q->param('PE_FQDN');

$sth = $dbh_source2->prepare($SEL);
print '<table border=1>';
print '<tr>';
print '<th>SUR FQDN</th>';
print '<th>Tower Name</th>';
print '<th>Site ID</th>';
print '<th>SUR Link</th>';

print '</tr>';
foreach my $data_line (@raw_data) {
        chomp $data_line;

        $sth->execute($data_line);

        while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
              #Print data into cells#
              print "<tr>";
              print "<td>$data_line</td>";
              foreach (@row) {
                print "<td>$_</td>";
              }
              print "</tr>";
              #print "<$data_line>\t @row\n";

        }

}

print "</table>";
END {     
            $dbh_source2->disconnect if defined($dbh_source2);
}
```

~

```
The error:
[jgearh200@srv01-netops cgi-bin]$ ./tower_gather_script.cgi 
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 2 are needed [for Statement "SELECT DISTINCT SITE_NAME, SITEID, PE_DOWNLINK_PORT FROM CBHME.SERVICE_TOPOLOGY_VIEW WHERE LOWER(PE_FQDN) = ? OR PE_OSPF_LOOPBACK_IP = ?" with ParamValues: :p1=undef, :p2=undef] at ./tower_gather_script.cgi line 33.
DBD::Oracle::st fetchrow_array failed: ERROR no statement executing (perhaps you need to call execute first) [for Statement "SELECT DISTINCT SITE_NAME, SITEID, PE_DOWNLINK_PORT FROM CBHME.SERVICE_TOPOLOGY_VIEW WHERE LOWER(PE_FQDN) = ? OR PE_OSPF_LOOPBACK_IP = ?" with ParamValues: :p1=undef, :p2=undef] at ./tower_gather_script.cgi line 35.
<table border=1><tr><th>SUR FQDN</th><th>Tower Name</th><th>Site ID</th><th>SUR Link</th></tr></table>[jgearh200@srv01-netops cgi-bin]$
```

So what I want it to be able to do:

I have a text area in which a user enters an FQDN or IP address line by line of a device and it goes into the Oracle Database and grabs certain information.

The SELECT statement is trying to grab that information based on what the user inputs (IP or FQDN).

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? (And this is an Oracle SQL question, not a perl question).

Comment: Where is the Perl "or" statement? I think you are referring to the `OR` operator in the SQL statement.  What do you mean by "The OR statement does not work in this situation"?  Can you give an example of what you are expecting output and what is actually output?  Also, show how you are setting the parameters for the query, and how you are executing the query.

Comment: Basically it is not taking the OR statement in the SQL SELECT:

It brings out no output.  I am polling a database for either an FQDN or IP Address based on user input

Comment: "Hello, tech support?  Yes, my computer doesn't work. ...  What do you mean, 'what's wrong'!?  It doesn't work!"

Comment: @jmg0880 - If you actually want help, then you'll have to help us help you:  what error messages did you get (if any), what was the expected output, and what was the actual output?  And if I were you, I'd hurry up and edit your question before it gets closed (you likely have two minutes or less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 2 are needed...`

Well, there you go:  you need to bind two variables to the select statement (ie the parts in `$SEL` where there are question marks) instead of just one.

Comment: Sorry if I am unfamiliar with how would bind a second variable.  Would you mind showing me how to do so?

Comment: In your `execute` command, you need to have more than one variable as an argument.  Check out http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#execute

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the helpful information.  I am still very much a newbie at perl / SQL.

I apologize for any ignorance earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having trouble with binding variables to a query?

```
$query = "SELECT something FROM table WHERE firstname = ? AND lastname = ?";

$bindh = $dbh->prepare( $query )
   or die "Unable to prepare $query" . $dbh->errstr;

foreach $line ( @Array )
{
   ( $f1, $f2 ) = split( /\|/, "$line" );

   $bindh->execute( $f1, $f2 ) 
     or die "Unable to execute '$query'.  " . $bindh->errstr;

   @results = $bindh->fetchrow_array;
}
```